# Pattern matching on strings from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wanted to know if it was possible to do a pattern matching on a set of data from a table.

Like:

```
select * from Table where Column like any(select Pattern from PatternTable)
```

Note that the `Pattern` is always a substring of `Column`. Hence the use of like. Is it even possible to do this at a database level without the use of stored procedures?

If it helps, my RDBMS is MS SQL-Server

**Edit:**

Alright, I have a table containing a set of data like

```
PatternTable
____________
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Now, a table `Table` has the following data:

```
Table
______
SomeDatatest4SomeData
SomeDataSomeData
```

Now, can I use a query as mentioned above to find a match: For the above query, this should return `SomeDatatest4SomeData`

Comment: Post something more specific,as it is you`ll only get generic guesses.Show some sample data.

Comment: You can't use `any` for this. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187074(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Just wanted to know if it was possible using a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
select *
from Table t
where exists (select 1
              from PatternTable pt
              where t.Column like pt.Pattern
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM [Table] t
INNER JOIN PatternTable p ON t.[Column] LIKE '%' + p.Pattern + '%'
```